# SQL null row and COUNT

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of images

```
id |  url | albumID
------------------
 1 | null |   1
 2 | null |   1
 3 | null |   2
 4 | null |   5
```

and the table of comments

```
id |  text   | imageID
------------------
 1 | 'xD'    |   1
 2 |  ':)'   |   1
 3 | ':P'    |   1
 4 | '(_!_)' |   2
```

I want to get all of the images with albumID = 1 and number of comments with imageID matched to previous result.

```
SELECT images.id, COUNT(comments.imageID) AS comments FROM images 
LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.imageID=images.id
WHERE images.albumID=1
```

And I get:

```
id |  comments
------------------
 1 |     3
```

It is okay, but when I try to search for an image with a nonexistent albumID:

```
SELECT images.id, COUNT(comments.imageID) AS comments FROM images 
LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.imageID=images.id
WHERE images.albumID=3
```

And I get:

```
   id |  comments
------------------
 null |     0
```

I dont want to get result with null. So what is wrong with my query?

**EDIT:**

**SOLUTION 1**

by @cdaiga and @isaace, thank You

```
SELECT images.id, COUNT(comments.imageID) AS comments FROM images 
LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.imageID=images.id
WHERE images.albumID=3
GROUP BY images.id;
```

**SOLUTION 2**

by myself after thinking, but I'm not sure what about the performance of this solution

```
SELECT images.id, 
  (
   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments WHERE comments.imageID=images.id 
  ) AS comment FROM images 
WHERE images.albumID=3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally when you run:

```
SELECT images.id FROM images 
LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.imageID=images.id
WHERE images.albumID=3;
```

The result is an empty set.
But running:

```
SELECT images.id, COUNT(comments.imageID) AS comments FROM images 
LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.imageID=images.id
WHERE images.albumID=3;
```

Returns a null, and the count which is zero, because count is not used with an aggregation. To get the correct result you have to use count as an aggregate function by adding a group by clause.

```
SELECT images.id, COUNT(comments.imageID) AS comments FROM images 
LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.imageID=images.id
WHERE images.albumID=3
GROUP BY images.id;
```

Comment: if nothing is returned from the images table, why is it returning null and 0?

Comment: @cdiaga: There is no difference, the result is the same  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ceb946/4/0

Answer (score 2):

Normally when you run:

```
SELECT images.id FROM images 
LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.imageID=images.id
WHERE images.albumID=3;
```

The result is an empty set.
But running:

```
SELECT images.id, COUNT(comments.imageID) AS comments FROM images 
LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.imageID=images.id
WHERE images.albumID=3;
```

Returns a null, and the count which is zero, because count is not used as an aggregate function. To get the correct result you have to use count as an aggregate function by adding a group by clause.

```
SELECT images.id, COUNT(comments.imageID) AS comments FROM images 
LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.imageID=images.id
WHERE images.albumID=3
GROUP BY images.id;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you add a `GROUP BY` this should fix it.

```
SELECT images.id, COUNT(comments.imageID) AS comments FROM images 
LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.imageID=images.id
WHERE images.albumID=3
GROUP BY images.id
```

In later versions of `mysql` you wouldn't be able to run the query without the `GROUP BY`.